# Fischer mode backfiring

Tags: history, records, time-control

The idea of Fischer mode is (beside others) to shorten the game somewhat (without shortening the actual thinking time).

Now, the nightmare of any tournament director is two people playing a sea snake (that's what it is called in German), maybe a QP/Q endgame, unto the draw in the 250th move. Ruining the whole schedule (especially if it is a Swiss tournament).

What is the longest game ([not move-wise](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_world_records_in_chess), but time-wise) played after the advent of Fischer mode?